# An algorithm for summarizing content

Tags: c#, java, c++, algorithm, genetic-algorithm

I am looking at summarizing content on a website i am planning on building. Instead of pages and pages of content I would prefer to offer them a summary of each topic.

I have come across some idea on how I can do this, which are mainly to do with finding the most common words and writing a short form. This does help, even one character less makes a big difference.

Would anyone be kind enough to make some suggestions or point me to the right sources for the correct algorithms? I know I have to develop the algorithm myself but I am doing some research before I start.

Answer (score 0):

I think this gives a good overview of different summarization approaches: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_summarization

The NLTK toolkit should also be very useful as a starting point: http://nltk.org/ and it has been used to build summarizers e.g. https://github.com/amsqr/NaiveSumm